# How to get IntelliJ14 to show src files

Tags: intellij-14

As you can see, these are the files that show up. But I know that there is a folder called src with code in it. How can I get the src folder to appear in the project pane, like the other files/folders?

[image: The files that show up in IntelliJ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you imported this project wrongly. Since I see this is a Maven project, the easiest way to open it correctly is to simply do **File -> Open and choose the root pom.xml**. At this point it might ask you to open the existing project (your current, broken one) or delete the meta data and re-import - you want this last option. Previous versions also asked if you want to open the pom file itself or the entire project, but as of 14 the project is opened by default. In case you do not get asked to re-import, and the project still doesn't look good, **try manually deleting the .idea folder and all *.iml files in the project**, and retry.